# Sharing data between classes without objects

Tags: python, class, date, tkinter

I have an issue with sharing data between classes. I guess how it works with objects, but I need to share data without creating objects, for example:

```
class First_class:
    def __init__(self):
        var = 1 ##create some random variable

class Second_class:
    def on_click(self):
        print(var) ##working with variable from First_class

First_class()
Second_class()
```

Some ideas on how to make it or some better solution? btw I use Tkinter and these classes simulate frames with some widgets, so more specifics:

```
class Frame1:
    def __init__(self):
        name = Enter(root)

class Frame2:
    def on_click(self):
        print(name.get())

Frame1()
Frame2()
```

Comment: When you do `First_class()`  you are creating an object. Why aren't you just saving a reference so you can do something like `first = First_class(); print(first.var)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the variable as a class property instead of under **init**, as the class would *have* to be initialised in order to get that value.

```py
class First_class:
    var = 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Second_class:
    def on_click(self):
        print(First_class.var)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.:)